# is there a way with spaCy's NER to calculate metrics per entity type?

Tags: python, entity, metrics, spacy, named-entity-recognition

is there a way in the NER model in spaCy to extract the metrics (precision, recall, f1 score) per entity type?

Something that will look like this:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

  B-LOC      0.810     0.784     0.797      1084
  I-LOC      0.690     0.637     0.662       325
 B-MISC      0.731     0.569     0.640       339
 I-MISC      0.699     0.589     0.639       557
  B-ORG      0.807     0.832     0.820      1400
  I-ORG      0.852     0.786     0.818      1104
  B-PER      0.850     0.884     0.867       735
  I-PER      0.893     0.943     0.917       634
```

avg / total      0.809     0.787     0.796      6178

taken from: http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/05/09/Named_Entity_Evaluation/

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Nice question.

First, we should clarify that spaCy uses the BILUO annotation scheme instead of the BIO annotation scheme you are referring to. 
From the spacy [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#updating-biluo) the letters denote the following:

- B: The first token of a multi-token entity.
- I: An inner token of a multi-token entity.
- L: The final token of a multi-token entity.
- U: A single-token entity.
- O: A non-entity token.

Then, some definitions:

[image: definitions]

Spacy has a built-in class to evaluate NER. It's called **scorer**.
Scorer uses exact matching to evaluate NER. The precision score is returned as ents_p, the recall as ents_r and the F1 score as ents_f.

The only problem with that is that it returns the score for all the tags together in the document. However, we can call the function only with the TAG we want and get the desired result.

All together, the code should look like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
from spacy.scorer import Scorer

def evaluate(nlp, examples, ent='PERSON'):
    scorer = Scorer()
    for input_, annot in examples:
        text_entities = []
        for entity in annot.get('entities'):
            if ent in entity:
                text_entities.append(entity)
        doc_gold_text = nlp.make_doc(input_)
        gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=text_entities)
        pred_value = nlp(input_)
        scorer.score(pred_value, gold)
    return scorer.scores


examples = [
    ("Trump says he's answered Mueller's Russia inquiry questions \u2013 live",{"entities":[[0,5,"PERSON"],[25,32,"PERSON"],[35,41,"GPE"]]}),
    ("Alexander Zverev reaches ATP Finals semis then reminds Lendl who is boss",{"entities":[[0,16,"PERSON"],[55,60,"PERSON"]]}),
    ("Britain's worst landlord to take nine years to pay off string of fines",{"entities":[[0,7,"GPE"]]}),
    ("Tom Watson: people's vote more likely given weakness of May's position",{"entities":[[0,10,"PERSON"],[56,59,"PERSON"]]}),
]

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
results = evaluate(nlp, examples)
print(results)
```

Call the evaluate function with the proper ent parameter to get the results for each tag.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think there is something wrong with this, when I run the evaluation on all entities, I get very good results (>90% for P, R and F) however when I filter the entities using your function the R remains high, but P and F drop to extremely low (below 20%) So I'm thinking the function is evaluating incorrectly at the line GoldParse(). Maybe its taking into account all entities in the first parameter?

Comment: @gdaras I quote you "Scorer uses exact matching to evaluate NER" - How do you know this? You would help me by letting me know your source:) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From spacy v3,

#Test the model

```
import spacy
from spacy.training.example import Example

nlp = spacy.load("./model_saved")
examples = []
data = [("Taj mahal is in Agra.", {"entities": [(0, 9, 'name'),
(16, 20, 'place')]})]
for text, annots in data:
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
    examples.append(Example.from_dict(doc, annots))
print(nlp.evaluate(examples)) # This will provide overall and per entity metrics
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been working on this, and now its integrated withing spacy by this [Pull Request](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/3911).

Now you just need to call `Scorer().scores` and it will return the usual dict with an additional key, `ents_per_type`, that will contains the metrics Precision, Recall and F1-Score for each entity.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @gdaras can you have a look at my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376213/calculate-all-the-metrics-of-a-custom-named-entity-recognition-nermodel-using

Comment: can you have look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376213/calculate-all-the-metrics-of-a-custom-named-entity-recognition-nermodel-using

Answer (score 2):

@gdaras 's answer is not right. The first comment gives the idea why.
You should filter entities of

```
pred_value = nlp(input_)
```

I did it like this

```
pred_value.ents = [e for e in pred_value.ents if e.label_ == ent]
```

Comment: @Ruwan, I did not get your point exactly , where should I add this?

Comment: Use @gdaras 's answer as a starting point.  You should add my second line right after my first one (find it in the first answer).  Use similar filtering for *text_entities* before    *gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=text_entities)*

Comment: Can you rewrite the code chunk in your answer as it is confusing ?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the NER model calculating the metric per entity type can be performed by using spacy's built-in scorer class.

It outputs dict with the key ***ents_per_type*** containing precision, recall, f1-score for each entity.

For spacy v3 supported data format for training (extracted from UBIAI),

```py
valid_data = [
    {
        "documentName": "file.txt",
        "document": "Ram lives in Kathmandu, Nepal.",
        "annotation": [
            {
                "start": 0,
                "end": 3,
                "label": "PER",
                "text": "Ram",
                "propertiesList": [],
                "commentsList": []
            },
            ...
            ],
        "user_input": ""
    }]
```

```py
import spacy
from spacy.training import Example
from spacy.scorer import Scorer

nlp = spacy.load("path_to_your_model")
scorer = Scorer()

examples = []
annots = []

for content in valid_data:
    predicted = nlp(content['document'])
    for annotate_content in content['annotation']:
        start = annotate_content['start']
        end = annotate_content['end']
        label = annotate_content['label']
        annots.append((start, end, label))
   
    final = {'entities': annots}
    
    example = Example.from_dict(predicted, final)
    examples.append(example)

scores = scorer.score(examples)
scores['ents_per_type']
```

Also, You can simply create a test dataset with the number of annotated data samples and run the following command to calculate the metrics per entity type.

```py
!spacy evaluate path_to_your_model path_to_your_test_data
```

```py
!spacy evaluate ./output/model-best ./data/test.spacy
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes the results come like this:

```
{'token_acc': 1.0, 'token_p': 1.0, 'token_r': 1.0, 'token_f': 1.0, 'ents_p': 0.8571428571428571, 'ents_r': 0.5454545454545454, 'ents_f': 0.6666666666666665, 'ents_per_type': {'KEY5': {'p': 0.8571428571428571, 'r': 0.5454545454545454, 'f': 0.6666666666666665}}, 'speed': 34577.72779537917}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice output put does not explain anything about how to make it